# how to change color of CheckedlistBox selected Value in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net

I need to Search Item with Text Box .If it founds We need to Highlight that Item in a Checked List box.I tried as below

`clbItems.Items[foundIndex].Attributes.Add("style", "background-color:#BBBBBB; color: white;");`

its working by removing Update panel.

I have following code in

```
 for (int itemcount = 0; itemcount < (p as CheckBoxList).Items.Count; itemcount++)
                                        {
                                            if ((p as CheckBoxList).Items[itemcount].Text.ToUpper().StartsWith(txtClientSearch.Text.ToUpper()))
                                            {
                                                ListItem lst1 = new ListItem((p as CheckBoxList).Items[itemcount].Text);
                                                (p as CheckBoxList).Items.RemoveAt(itemcount);
                                                (p as CheckBoxList).Items.Insert(0, lst1);
                                                (p as CheckBoxList).Items[0].Attributes.Add("style", "background-color:yellow;color:Red");
                                            }

                                        }
```

Can any one suggest me the way to achieve this in Javascript .

Thanks ,
Rakesh.

Answer (score 0):

This iss how you do it from code behind

```
  CheckBoxList1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "checkBoxList1OnCheck(this);");
```

If you want to use javascripts see this eg :

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
 <asp:CheckBoxList id="CheckBoxList1" onclick="checkBoxList1OnCheck(this);" runat="server">
  <asp:listitem value="1">Item 1</asp:listitem>
  <asp:listitem value="2">Item 2</asp:listitem>
  <asp:listitem value="3">Item 3</asp:listitem>
 </asp:CheckBoxList>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function checkBoxList1OnCheck(listControlRef)
{
 var inputItemArray = listControlRef.getElementsByTagName('input');

 for (var i=0; i<inputItemArray.length; i++)
 {
  var inputItem = inputItemArray[i];

  if ( inputItem.checked )
  {
   inputItem.parentElement.style.backgroundColor = 'Red';
  }
  else
  {
   inputItem.parentElement.style.backgroundColor = 'White';
  }
 }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Please tell me how to change Background color  when selected .

Comment: Previously I used Update Panel so this effect didn't appear..Now its working fine ..Is it possible to Compare textbox.Text with CheckBoxlist Items for search purpose ?